# Mqsql Email $link Message

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, email

Hello I am making a email system for my school project. I wanting someone to help with getting it to display the password hash in the html document part. At the moment it doesn't display anything. Thank you Joshua

```
<?php require_once 'application/config/autoload.php'; 

    $host= DB_HOST;
    $username= DB_USER;;
    $password= DB_PASS;
    $db_name= DB_NAME;
    $tbl_name= DB_TABLE;
    $user_name = Session::get('user_name');


error_reporting(0);

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");


            $sql = "SELECT user_id,
                           user_name,
                           user_email,
                           user_password_reset_hash,
                           user_perm_level,
                           user_type,
                           user_active,
                           user_failed_logins,
                           user_last_failed_login
                           FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name='$user_name'";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($result){
            $link = "$result->user_password_reset_hash";
            echo "<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>

<div>
    <img src='logo.min.png' align='left'></p>
    <h1 align='right'>Teacher Help</h1>
    <h2 align='right'>Verify Email<br></h2>
    <p>$link</p>
</div>
</head>
</html>"; } ?>
```

Comment: U can easily do it with MD5.js using jquery...

Comment: i m saying if u want to encrypt ur password then use md5.js...

Answer (score 0):

First, change your `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` since it is already deprecated. Now, your could should be like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

$sql = "SELECT user_id,
  user_name,
  user_email,
  user_password_reset_hash,
  user_perm_level,
  user_type,
  user_active,
  user_failed_logins,
  user_last_failed_login
  FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name='$user_name'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
    $link = $row["user_password_reset_hash"];
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: i will give it a try in 10 min

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it as an array

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$link = $row['user_password_reset_hash'];
```

*Obviously `mysql` is deprecated and you should consider using `pdo` or `mysqli`. As it's a project with a specific question, i have answered accordingly.*

Answer (score 0):

You've got to fetch the content of your result. Your code tells me, you want to use [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

```
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result){
            $row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
            $link = $row->user_password_reset_hash;
            echo $link;
            // ...
```

I'm sorry that you learn at school to use those old deprecated mysql_* functions (see the red box in the linked manual page). You're better off with the mysqli extension or PDO, shown in [the answer of lodev09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24584462/mqsql-email-link-message#24584520). With PDO or mysqli you should use prepared statements with placeholders and put the input values to those placeholders to avoid sql injection.

Comment: How world i add a <input type='submit' button with $link variable

Comment: Either use a simple link with a href attribute like `resetscript.php?hash=<the urlencoded reset hash>` or you create a form with an hidden input element with the hash as value and an submit button. There are thousands of other ways, but this is a school project, so I would implement either the link or the form with the hidden field.

Comment: I have another problem when i reset pass it gives me the code before it

Comment: @user3761831 You should consider a separate question for this new problem.

Comment: Ok i will make one please consider to help on new one

Comment: I will have to wait to its been 90 min since this one